# Storing asian language characters in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm running into a problem where if I attempt to store asian language data such as mandarin, korean, japanese in my database it will display as a series of `??????????` question mark strings.

Is there anything in particular that i must do to be able to store foreign languages in SQL Server 2016?

I'm using mainly `varchar` datatypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unicode characters, you must use nvarchar. Then your values should appear correctly.